# Javascript variable is empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml

[image]
I have a an xml file that I'm using as a database for my website. I have a table that contains all the products of the website. When you add a product to the xml, it automatically updates the table (see image).

Now, I want to be able to delete the product from here also by clicking the delete button. I want to delete the product by grabbing the name of the product by Javascript and sending that name back to php for processing the xml.

Here's the problem: When I try to grab the product name from the table, the string is empty when I do console.log. How can I solve this?

Here is some relevant code:

This is the part of the Javascript where I am reading the xml file to append the info of the product from xml to the website:

```
                //name
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = productNode.children[0].innerHTML;
                row.appendChild(td);

                //price
                td = document.createElement('td');
                let price = productNode.children[4].innerHTML;
                let priceArray = price.split(',');
                let priceList = makeUL(priceArray);
                td.appendChild(priceList);
                row.appendChild(td);

                //type 
                td = document.createElement('td');
                let type = productNode.children[6].innerHTML;
                let typeArray = type.split(',');
                let typeList = makeUL(typeArray);
                td.appendChild(typeList);
                row.appendChild(td);

                console.log("running..........")


                //size
                td = document.createElement('td');
                let size = productNode.children[5].innerHTML;
                let sizeArray = size.split(',');
                let sizeList = makeUL(sizeArray);
                td.appendChild(sizeList);
                row.appendChild(td);

                //quantity
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = productNode.children[2].innerHTML;
                row.appendChild(td);

                //stock
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = productNode.children[3].innerHTML;
                row.appendChild(td);


                //buttons to remove and edit (not pulled from database)
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = "<a href='edit_product.html' class='btn btn-outline-dark'>Edit</a>  <a href='#myModal' name='delete' onclick=deleteProduct() class='btn btn-outline-danger' >Remove</a>"
                row.appendChild(td);
            
                productTable.children[1].appendChild(row);
```

And here is the Javascript for sending info to the server:

```
 function deleteProduct() {
    let productName = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
    console.log(productName);
    $.post("deleteProduct.php", {prodName : productName});
}
```

In this segment, when I do console.log(productName), it doesn't print anything, hence the server can't process it.

Comment: Inline bindings do not have context associated with them.  `console.log(this)` to show this.

Comment: Create a real event listener on the elements, or change it to `onclick="deleteProduct(this)"` and pass the link into the method.

Comment: can you write it in the answer with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to fix this is to pass the element in on the method call.

```
onclick="deleteProduct(this)"
```

And then your method would accept the link in as an argument and use it.

```
function deleteProduct(link) {
    let productName = $(link).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
    console.log(productName);
    $.post("deleteProduct.php", {prodName : productName});
}
```

However, the *preferred* way would be to either make an actual event handler on the elements, which would have context, or to make a delegate event handler higher up on a shared parent of all the elements that would perform the logic.

jQuery Direct Bindings: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

jQuery Delegate Event Bindings: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: thank you, but how would you use the element that is passed inside the deleteProduct() function? Sorry, i'm new to this...

Comment: I just added the function snippet.

Comment: ok thank you, but it still seems to print out nothing

Comment: You will need to debug what `$(link).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)')` is finding and verify that it is the correct element.